# Code readability : if foreach conditions in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-statements, code-readability

What is the better practice and best readability for you :

```
foreach ($k as $v) {

   if($v == 10) {
       continue;
   }

   // continue code ...
}
```

Or :

```
foreach ($k as $v) {

   if($v != 10) {
       // code ...
   }

}
```

Maybe it's stupid, but I often ask myself this question.
What do you think it ?

Comment: i think go with second one that is better.

Comment: That is opinion based and off-topic here. (I for example would choose based on the code and the logic and what makes more sense.)

Comment: as far as i understand it, the second one is O(1) faster. so you can totaly ignore it, and go with your prefered way!

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a poll than a question, and as such, no answer will be correct.

But, generally if your `if` is a negation or is easily written as an else case to a corresponding `if` (as in `if ($v == 10) {} else {/*...*/}`), I would go with the `continue`. So if I want to run all cases for `$v` except a few exceptions, I would filter these exceptions in the start and do a `continue` for them.

So, I would prefer:

```
foreach ($k as $v) {

   if($v == 10) {
       continue;
   }

   // code ...
}
```

The reason for this is that when more exceptions arise, they can be added easily like this.

```
foreach ($k as $v) {
   if($v == 10 || $v == 29) {
       continue;
   }
   if($v = 12) {
       continue;
   }

   // ... code
}
```

Granted, this could also be accomplished with an

```
if ($v != 10 && $v != 29 && $v != 12) {
    // ... code
}
```

but this `if` cannot be slit into multiple conditions which can quickly grow to be more complex to read and understand than is ideal as time adds more and more exceptions.

Take this example. Which do you think is clearer and less mentally challenging to grasp?

```
foreach ($k as $i => $v) {
    if ($i = 8) { continue; }
    if ($i % 3) { continue; }
    if ($v['foo'] == 'bar') { continue; }
    if ($v['bar'] == 'foo') { continue; }
    if ($v['foobar'] == 10) { continue; }
    if ($v['value'] < 0 || $v['value'] > 100) { continue; }

    // else, do code...
}
```

Or...

```
foreach ($k as $i => $v) {
    if ($i != 8 && !($i & 3) && $v['foo'] != 'bar' && $v['bar'] != 'foo' && $v['foobar'] != 10 && $v['value'] >= 0 && $v['value'] <= 100) {
        // do code ...
    }
}
```

Also, I have found that negations are harder to comprehend (*do this if not equals 10* is more prone for a mental slip than *skip if equals 10*).

As a sidenote, If you are coding in a multi-cultural setting, you also may have to consider that same cultures and languages don't have native negations in their language, so the very concept of a negation is an alien feature which even experienced programmers sometimes can miss out on when just quickly browsing your code. This may or may not be something you need to take into consideration, though.

Answer (score 0):

This question is based on the coding standards you work with in my opinion.

I prefer

```
foreach ($k as $v) {
   if($v != 10) {
       // code ...
   }
}
```

This way i will know it will do something only when `$v` is different from 10. The first option says it will continue, same result. But you have if, then some code, you may get confused.

The answer still is on based what you prefer.

Comment: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* -- opinion based questions are off-topic, since there is never a definitive answer to them. So answering them doesn't help, since you never can answer them correctly.